# How Can I display x axis with the datetime values and y axis with mililiters values from the firebase-database

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

This is the part of the code that i put the point values to the firebase and take the data from the firebase. i want to display the x axis values with the time value on the day and y axis with the value. how should i do using this library called "implementation com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3"

```
private void setListeners() {
            btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    String id=reference.push().getKey();

                    long xl=new Date().getTime();
                    int x=(int) xl;
    //                long now = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //                int x=(int) now;

    //                String x= String.valueOf(x1);
    //                int x=Integer.parseInt(xValue.getText().toString());
                    int y=Integer.parseInt(yValue.getText().toString());

    //                PointValue pointValue=new PointValue(x,y);
                    PointValue pointValue=new PointValue(x,y);

                    reference.child(id).setValue(pointValue);
                }
            });
        }

        private void DataShow(){

            ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                    Entry[] dp= new Entry[(int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()];
                    int index=0;
                    int sum=0;
                    int max=0;
                    int min=0;

                    for(DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        PointValue pointValue=myDataSnapshot.getValue(PointValue.class);

                        dp[index] = new Entry(index+1, pointValue.getyValue());
                        yValues.add(dp[index]);
                        index++;
                        sum+=pointValue.getyValue();
                        if(min==0 && max==0){
                            min=pointValue.getyValue();
                            max=pointValue.getyValue();
                        }
                        if(pointValue.getyValue()>max) max=pointValue.getyValue();
                        if(pointValue.getyValue()<min) min=pointValue.getyValue();
                    }
                    int Avg=0;
                    Log.v(TAG,"Index: "+index);

                    if(index!=0)
                        Avg=sum/index;

                    values.setText("Minimum value : "+ min+" ml"+"\n Average Value : "+ Avg +" ml"+"\n Maximum Value : "+max+" ml"+"\n");
                    set=createSet();
                    data.addDataSet(set);
                    data.notifyDataChanged();
                    mChart.setData(data);
                    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mChart.animateX(3000);
                    mChart.invalidate();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Getting Post failed, log a message
                    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    // ...
                }
            };
            reference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
        }
```

Please give a guidelines to do this task.

Thank you

Comment: And what is the behaviour when using this code?

Comment: The thing is, the  time value that i passed to the firebase, how can i display in the x axis. it's the challenge...